# minetest loops with post_effect_color not working with lua table

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table

Can anyone help me with getting post_effect_color to work with table.

```
local UNDERWATERCOLOR = {
    "a=64, r=1, g=255, b=1", --green
    "a=64, r=1, g=1, b=255" --blue
}

for i = 1, 2 do

    local underwatercolor = UNDERWATERCOLOR[i]

    -- water
    minetest.register_node("coloredwater:water_source_" .. color .. "", {
            post_effect_color = {".. underwatercolor .."},
    })

end
```

for anyone who what to view the code in full can do so hear https://github.com/Sinkidonk/Minetest_coloredwater/blob/master/looptest.lua

What I what is that the underwater colored to be the color value in the table which is post_effect_color.

Or in other word when the for loop, do it first loop I what the value of `post_effect_color = {".. underwatercolor .."}` to be `post_effect_color = {a=64, r=1, g=255, b=1}` and so on.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a string in `UNDERWATERCOLOR` instead of just using tables?

Comment: sorry I not 100% sure what you are saying are you saying why did I use `post_effect_color = {".. underwatercolor .."}` if that what your asking then it because I don't know how to use it using only a table.

Comment: Why are you doing `UNDERWATERCOLOR = { "a=64, r=1, g=255, b=1", ...}` (which is a table of string value) instead of `UNDERWATERCOLOR = { {a=64, r=1, g=255, b=1}, ...}` (which is a table of table values). With strings you need to wrap them in `{` and `}` and then use something like `dostring` to run that string as lua code to get a table as a result.

Comment: ok I try and testing that out and it did not seem to make a different to the outcome I wanted to get. As for why I did it that way it did not seem to make any different in how I did it.

Comment: I don't know what "that" is in this case. If you use tables in the source you will have tables in the result. If you use a string and need a table you need to get lua to run the string as code to get a table as output (see my comment about `dostring`).

Comment: sorry for the vague answer there 'that' is what you posted me to try the table of table values. and I did try out your comment about `dostring` and no manner how I did it the outcome was the same.

Comment: Something like `post_effect_color = dostring("return {"..underwatercolor.."}")` should work but just using tables in the first place is likely simpler and more straightforward.

Comment: ok I try what you posting with the `UNDERWATERCOLOR` table as a table of string values, and also as a table of table values, and I get this error when I did it as a table to string values `attempt to call global 'dostring' (a nil value)` so it think that dostring is a variable, as far as I know it not. When I did it as a table to table values I get this error `attempt to concatenate local 'underwatercolor' (a table value)` now what that mean I got no idea. I am starting to think it a bug in minetest that is stopping `post_effect_color` from working with table input. or something like that.

Comment: Use `loadstring(post_effect_color)()` instead of `dostring` (though you should probably have error checking there too). And why are you trying to concatenate the table with anything? You don't need the `"{"..` and `.."}"` bits if you use a table. And no, there's no bug here other than your not quite understanding how this all works.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the colors as a table instead of a string, then plug into the definition directly. I also fixed `color` not being available by taking it from the key

```
local UNDERWATERCOLOR = {
    green = { a=64, r=1, g=255, b=1 } ,
    blue  = { a=64, r=1, g=1,   b=25 },
}

-- Iterate through waters.
-- Color wll be the key (green or blue)
-- underwatercolor will be the value (one of the tables above)
for color, underwatercolor in pairs(UNDERWATERCOLOR) do
    -- water
    minetest.register_node("coloredwater:water_source_" .. color .. "", {
            post_effect_color = underwatercolor,
    })
end
```